# bridged network not working

Tags: wireless, networking

NAT works fine and I have internet connection, but bridged connection not working. I have tried quiet a few things, including resetting MAC address for bridged adapter:

[image]

when I do ifconfig it does not show eth0

[image]

But when I look in interfaces eth0 is in there as shown below:

[image]

It was working before so I don't know what could be the issue. I also noticed when I restart VM it stalls for a while saying configuring network settings or something along those lines but I am guessing it never receives the settings.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it by just deleting everything located in persistent-net rules:

```
sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
```

and then rebooting

explanation as to why this is so can be found [here](http://www.serenux.com/2009/11/howto-fix-a-missing-eth0-adapter-after-moving-ubuntu-server-from-one-box-to-another/)